# Dynamically create checkboxes and add change handlers for the same : Semantic-ui-react + React

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I am trying to create dynamic checkboxes using semantic-ui-react I have object of the following structure. I want the checkbox value should get applied to the particular object in this array. I am unable to do it with the change handler provided below. Can someone help me with this?

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-pine-r5dpi

```
import { Checkbox } from "semantic-ui-react";

checkboxArray = [
                  {name: "firstName", value: "firstName", show: true, displayValue: " First Name"},
                  {name: "status", value: "status", show: true, displayValue: " Status "},
                  {name: "visits", value: "visits", show: true, displayValue: " Visits "}
];

Checkbox Change Handler
--------------------------
 handleItemClick = (e,data) => {
    console.log(data.checked);
    this.setState({ [data.name]: data.checked });
  };

Inside Render
----------------
{this.state.optionsArr.map((item, i) => (
            <div key={i}>
              <Checkbox
                name={item.name}
                onChange={this.handleItemClick}
                checked={item.show}
                label={item.displayValue}
              />
            </div>
))}
```

Comment: Could you show how your state is looking like?

Comment: @Claeusdev State object I have given in the question. It is as same as checkboxArray.  I am able to bring the checkboxes but operations on checkbox is not working. I want the show property to be updated based on the checkbox change for that object

Comment: @Claeusdev Have updated the question with a link to codesandbox

Comment: I don't see any issue with the codesandbox. or has it been solved?

Comment: @Claeusdev yes sandbox is working fine. when in application , event.target.checked is coming undefined. event.target is coming as <label>...</label>. So it is not setting. Any idea why?      object.show = event.target.checked value is coming as undefined, where as in sandbox it is true/false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`semantic-ui-react` takes a function for `onChange(event, data: object)`. `event` is the default synthetic event from React and `data` carries everything on the props. I think your `checked` is on the `data` object. try `data.checked` instead of `event.target.checked`

```
handleItemClick = (event, data, i) => {
    const { optionsArray } = this.state;
    optionsArray[i].show = !optionsArray[i].show;
    this.setState(() => {
      return optionsArray;
    });
  };

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.optionsArray);
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.optionsArray.map((item, i) => (
          <div key={i}>
            <Form.Checkbox
              name={item.name}
              onChange={(e, v) => this.handleItemClick(e, v, i)}
              value={item.show}
              defaultChecked={item.show}
              label={item.displayValue}
            />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

I have edited your code on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-mcclintock-zzuii)

Comment: I have edited the code, check and let's see if that's what you're looking for

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195530/discussion-between-claeusdev-and-vrosario).

Comment: Thanks much ! Appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the code in the sandbox, try changing your `handleItemClick` handler to:

```
handleItemClick = name => event => {
    let object,
      newOptionsArray = [...this.state.optionsArray];

    for (var i = 0; i < newOptionsArray.length; i++) {
      if (newOptionsArray[i].name === name) {
        object = newOptionsArray[i];
      }
    }

    object.show = event.target.checked;

    this.setState({
      ...this.state.optionsArray,
      object
    });
  };
```

And try changing the way you call the handler in the `onChange` event like this:

```
onChange={this.handleItemClick(item.name)}
```

Comment: No It is not . I have applied your changes as well , no luck

Comment: @vrosario Updated answer.

Comment: @vrosario Please check [the sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-murdock-81k9h). I do not see the issue you mention there :)

Comment: @vrosario Well I think you need to update your question with the relevant information on what you are doing differently on your application.

Comment: check this sandbox, same code https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-robinson-w4mth. It shows the issue